# AmCharts: How to access values showing in legend

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

I'm trying to manipulate the values that are shown in the legend while hovering over the chart with ChartCursor (i have connected a listener function for it but can't seem to find how each object shows each current value in the legend):

[image]

I have tried accessing with valueText using

```
chart.legend.valueText
```

But if i replace the valueText the value set will occur for every object in the legend. I would like to be able to reach every single object in the legend and be able to manipulate each objects' valueText.

The listener is implemented in chartCursor:

```
"chartCursor": {
        "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
        "listeners": [{
          "event": "changed",
          "method": cursorChanged
        }]
      },
```

Does someone know how to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access the legend values, you have to create a [`valueFunction`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmLegend#valueFunction) inside the legend object:

```
    "legend": {
        // ...
        "valueFunction": function(graphDataItem, valueText) {
            //check if valueText is empty. 
            //this only occurs when you're not currently hovered over a value
            //and if you don't have a periodValueText set.
          if (valueText !== " ") { 
            //access the current graph's value through the graph.valueField 
            //inside the graphDataItem parameter, 
            //or the string version of the value in valueText and manipulate it accordingly
            return graphDataItem.dataContext[graphDataItem.graph.valueField]; //current hovered value
          } else {
           return valueText; 
          }
        }
    },
```

The `valueFunction` is called for each graph object that has a visible legend marker.

[Demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/89df6d919ee30205118e68994742abe8?editors=0010)